# Macbook and iPhone not discoverable on bluetooth or airdrop

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, macos, bluetooth, airdrop

I am unable to use the AirDrop feature between my iPhone6s (iOS 9) and my 2014 MBP running OSX 10.11.1 (Mavericks). The jPhone won't show up in the MBP's AirDrop window (accessed from `Finder>Go>AirDrop`) and vice versa.

I was able to use my phone with another MBP with Mavericks flawlessly. I also tried to directly link them using Bluetooth (since AirDrop works via Bluetooth) and they were still unable to discover each other. I'm not sure whether this worked on Yosemite.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong with the Bluetooth discoverability, but I found a fix. It also fixes AirDrop since Bluetooth is its underlying technology.

You just need to delete a certain file, in my case I chose to rename it so I still had the original. You can do that using `Finder` or in the `Terminal` with the following command:

`sudo mv /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist.orig`

Do this then restart Bluetooth and your devices should now be discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

In order for my air drop to work on my MAC, I changed my firewall settings.

~System Preferences
~Security & Privacy
~Click the lock
~Firewall Options
~ "Blocked all-" should be UNchecked (it's the very first box at the top.)
~Make sure you allow every option that pops up